# Github push does not work in android studio

Tags: git, android-studio, github

I am trying to push the modification on Github but it is showing me this error:

> nvocation failed Unexpected end of file from server
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Invocation failed Unexpected end of file
> from server at git4idea.GitAppUtil.sendXmlRequest(GitAppUtil.java:30)
> at git4idea.http.GitAskPassApp.main(GitAskPassApp.java:58) Caused by:
> java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server at
> java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:866)
> at
> java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:689)
> at
> java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:863)
> at
> java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:689)
> at
> java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1615)
> at
> java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1520)
> at
> org.apache.xmlrpc.DefaultXmlRpcTransport.sendXmlRpc(DefaultXmlRpcTransport.java:87)
> at
> org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcClientWorker.execute(XmlRpcClientWorker.java:72)
> at org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:194) at
> org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:185) at
> org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:178) at
> git4idea.GitAppUtil.sendXmlRequest(GitAppUtil.java:27) ... 1 more
> unable to read askpass response from
> '/home/al3x4ndru1/.cache/Google/AndroidStudio2021.2/tmp/intellij-git-askpass-local.sh'
> could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or
> address

Comment: You are using an `https://` URL. When you do this, Git must obtain a *user name* and *password-or-token*, i.e., *credentials*, to *authenticate* you on GitHub. (GitHub uses tokens instead of passwords, but tokens are just structured passwords; Git thinks of them as passwords.) AndroidStudio blocks Git's access to your keyboard so that Git cannot read the user name and password from you. You'll need to supply them in some other way, or use an `ssh://` URL instead of the `https://` one you are using now.

Comment: To supply user name and password *to* Git, so that Git does not have to read them from your keyboard, use a *credential helper*. Search for "git credential helper" and you will find lots of helpful articles here.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me when I had the same error
In studio terminal
type git push -f
error was : remote: Invalid username or password.
An authentication link will appear with that error.
Please click and complete authentication in your browser.
Then you should be able to push the code.

Answer (score 0):

Download new vertion of git. I was also facing similar problem tried many solutions but none worked. Just update your git to the latest version.